# Which pattern to update interface using background thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, coding-style

I'm looking for a common and elegant way to manage interfaces update.
I know that user interface code must be run in main thread, so when i need some computation o network task i use GDC with this pattern:

```
dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(aQueue, ^() {

//Backgroud code

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //Update the UI
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that i need always check if user has changed view during my computation, so the code is like:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (mylabel != nil)  && ([mylabel superview] != nil) {
        mylabel.text = _result_from_computation_;
    }
}
```

There is some best ways?

Thanks.

Comment: another problem with this code is in the classic "master->detail" layout. When i show an object in the detailview i must be sure that in don't receive any "old" update.

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/c-mutex-examples/

Comment: i don't see mutex as good solution: I may be wrong but looks like he wanna take the whole code async. About the code: it's safe to call a selector like setText on a nil object, so the (mylabel != nil) test is not needed. Still not a solution, just less code to write...

Comment: Maybe I can use MVC in the original way, my model can send a notification to the controller when the background code ends.

Comment: Oh, I guessed you needed to update UI while the background process was running, not at the end. Anyway send a notification or use some KVO should work, even if may require more boilerplate code.

Comment: Could you explain a little about the harm involved in updating `mylabel` if it's offscren? What situation are you averting there?

Answer (score 1):

You pretty well have it. However, in case you want to do more reading or want a more thorough explanation of what's going on...

You should read the Apple Docs [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) and watch the WWDC 2012 video, *Session 712 - Asynchronous Design Patters with Blocks, GCD and XPC*.

If you're working with iOS, you can disregard XPC (interprocess communication) as it's not supported by the current OS version (6.1 at the time of this writing).

**Example:** Load a large image in the background and set the image when completed.

```
@interface MyClass ()
@property (strong) dispatch_block_t task;
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.task = ^{
        // Background Thread, i.e., your task
        NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Main Thread, setting the loaded image
            [view setImage:image];
        });
    });
}

- (IBAction)cancelTaskButtonClick:(id)sender {  // This can be -viewWillDisappear
    self.task = nil;  // Cancels this enqueued item in default global queue
}

- (IBAction)runTaskButtonClick:(id)sender {
    // Main Thread
    dispatch_queue_t queue;
    queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, self.task);
}
```

In order to cancel and reload the interface later, all you have to do is set the dispatch_block_t variable to nil.

Perhaps more specifically to your problem, this example piece of code deals with [*Reading Data from a Descriptor*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH103-SW6), i.e., either the disk or network.

Typically, you would use the Call-Callback pattern which essentially gets a background thread, executes a task, and when completed calls another block to get the main thread to update the UI.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer. Are you sure i can set `self.task = nil`and this will stop the execution of block? In this case i need to re-create a task for every object i need to show...

Comment: Yes. The example only queues one object. You can have an array of task elements and enqueue any of those tasks that you deem necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the view window property:

```
if (myLabel.window) {
  // update label
}
```

this is redundant `if (label != nil)` since if label is nil, then all label properties will also be nil (or zero) and setting them will not raise an exception.